# Sh - Get next array element

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am getting twice the arguments used with my script :

The first time using this following code, to make sure there isn't arguments that I don't want (I only take in consideration arg1:arg2:arg3)

```
     PARAM=$@
     while [ "$#" -gt "0" ]; do
              case $1 in
                       arg1)
                                shift2
                                ;;
                       arg2)
                                shift
                                ;;
                       arg3)
                                shift
                                ;;
                       *)
                                echo "Usage : ./test.sh arg1 <VAL1> <VAL2> [arg2] [arg3]"
                                exit 2
                                ;;
              esac
              shift
     done
```

And I would like to parse those arguments all over again and be able able to get the two following arguments when I get arg1, so I started with something like this :

```
     for command in $PARAM
     do
         case $command in
             arg1)
                 shift
                 VALUE1=$command
                 shift
                 VALUE2=$command
                 exec_arg1
                 ;;
         esac
         shift
```

But while using "shift", I get the error *shift: can't shift that many*

The shebang is "#!/bin/sh" and I am looking for a solution without having to use bash's shebang (i.e. "#!/bin/bash")

Comment: @ZackDibe What exactly do you mean with "mixed args position"?

Comment: What is `shift2`? A missing space? Also, `shift` changes `$@` not `$command`, so do not assign `$command` but `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot concatenate a list to a string and safely turn it back into a list (without a [complex helper function](https://github.com/vaeth/push/)). See [this FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

`shift` behaves differently in different shells. In Bash and Zsh, when no positional parameters remain, `shift` simply returns false. Many shells including Dash (contrary to POSIX, perhaps because of ksh behavior) throw a fatal error instead. ksh93 provides a way around this via the `command` builtin, but this also appears to be not specified by POSIX, though this workaroud also works in Dash anyway, but not `mksh` (there's also a bug in mksh that I just discovered yesterday that prevents this from working, and the maintainer probably won't fix it in a way that allows the workaround). Busybox doesn't follow POSIX either and gives no meaningful exit code.

Anyway, the point is you can't rely upon `shift` because so many shells have bugs here. You should iterate arguments without shifting them if possible and test the number of remaining arguments in a way that ensures you aren't shifting over the edge like you're currently doing. I don't think your idea of pre-validating the arguments is better than just validating and parsing at the same time.

```
#!/bin/sh

f()
    if ! ${_called_f+false}; then
        while ! ${1+false}; do
            case $1 in
                arg1)
                    ${3+:} return 1
                    value1=$2 value2=$3
                    shift 3
                    exec_arg1
                    ;;
                arg[23])
                    ${2+:} return 1
                    value1=$1
                    shift
                    "exec_arg${value1##"${value1%?}"}" # Only do this crap if restricted to POSIX
                    ;;
                *)
                    return 1
            esac
        done
    else
        # Hack nobody will understand since this probably isn't what you want anyway.
        _called_f= value1= value2= command eval \
            'typeset +x value{1,2} 2>/dev/null; f "$@"'
    fi

if ! f "$@"; then
    echo 'Error parsing args, exiting...' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

See also: [option parsing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035)